# How to give the keyboard focus in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

It's possible to designate a key as associated with a NetLogo button. But the key-press will not activate the button unless the keyboard is in the appropriate state. (I'm not sure what to call that state.) For example, when one starts a model, keys do not activate buttons until one clicks the background outside both the view and the command center. (Try Games > Frogger, Minesweeper, etc. in the Models library.) Also, if one types into the command center, one must click outside to re-active the key-button connections.

Is there a way to activate the keyboard-button connections with code -- so that it can be done, e.g., in setup?

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't under programmatic control, and it's by design that the command center normally has keyboard focus.

As a user, the easiest thing to do is hide the command center (there's even a keyboard shortcut for this) if you aren't using it, then the keyboard focus will be on the widgets.

Comment: In Games > Frogger, New Game > Start > <some command key> does not execute the associated button. But it doesn't put the key into the Command Center input line either. How/Why did they do that?

Comment: that sounds like a bug, the focus should always either be in the command center or the widget area